# Commerce products in Matrix

Tags: matrix, relations

I use Matrix to select products through a "Commerce Products" field type.

In the template, the following code displays nothing (not even an error in devMode.)

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixHandle %}
    {% set relatedProducts = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo({
        targetElement: entry, field: 'BlockTypeHandle.FieldHandle'
    }) %}

    {% for entry in relatedProducts %}
        {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Simplify your template.  Does `{% set relatedProducts = craft.commerce.products.relatedTo({
        targetElement: entry, field: 'BlockTypeHandle.FieldHandle'
    }) %}` by itself return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually have products selected in that entry's matrix products field, then

```
{% for block in entry.MatrixHandle %}
  {% if block.type.handle == "matrixProductsBlockTypeHandle"%}
    {% for product in block.productsFieldHandle %}
        {{ product.title }}
    {% endfor%}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That is the simplest approach really.  So if that doesn't work, triple confirm the `entry` vairable is the one you think it s and that you do indeed have chosen products in that field.  If still nothing, check the `craft.log` I guess!

Comment: Great Jeremy. I ended up doing this `{% set relatedProduct = block.matrixProductsBlockFieldHandle %} {% for product in relatedProducts %} ....` works perfectly